# Is it good style in JavaScript to call a function from the main thread and in a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multithreading, http

So I am very new to JavaScript and I know it does not have truly concurrent threads.  But if you imagine an ajax callback to be in its own thread and that callback draws some buttons on the screen and then calls a function `wire_up_buttons()` that sets callbacks for click events on all available buttons.  Is it good style to call that function from the main thread (i.e. the execution that started from `$(document).ready(callback)`?

If this is considered poor style then how would you recommend I change my code?

Comment: Not bad and not good. It depends on what you do in the commands block.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a matter of style. If you call `wire_up_buttons` from `$(document).ready(callback)` before your ajax call finishes, the buttons won't be there, and they won't get wired up. (Assuming `wire_up_buttons` hooks events on the buttons directly.)

You have two correct options:

1. Call `wire_up_buttons` from the `ajax` success handler after rendering the new buttons.
2. Make `wire_up_buttons` use *event delegation* on a container the buttons are all in, in which case calling it from your `ready` handler (if you want to use one) is likely to be the best thing to do.

Event delegation is where you actually hook the event on an element that is an *ancestor element* of the buttons, ideally some fairly localized container, but you can use `document` or `document.body` (since they're ancestors of all content elements on the page). Event delgation is supported by jQuery's `on` handler; its [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) has more information on it.

---

Side notes:

- *"I know [JavaScript] does not have truly concurrent threads."* That's an *environment* thing, not a language thing. Browsers provide truly-concurrent threads for JavaScript via [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/); they provide a single *UI* thread, but potentially several *non-UI* threads. JavaScript, the language, is essentially silent on the topic of threads. Reports of JavaScript being single-threaded are common, but incorrect.
- `ready` is largely unnecessary in code where you control where the `script` tags go. If you do, just put your `script` tags at the end of the HTML, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag, in which case there's no need for `ready`. More in the [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  At the moment my `wire_up_buttons` function just hooks up buttons to the "ids" of the buttons as gotten from the ajax callback.  And then registers callbacks on those buttons.  It also does other things like registering callbacks on other buttons.  Could you explain event delegation in this context please?

Comment: I don't think my question was clear enough.  I am calling the `wire_up_buttons()` function before the ajax request and in the callback as well.  So something will happen always